# decommission cassandra nodes after migration having initial_tokens set

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

Cassandra Version: Apache Cassandra 3.7
I have migrated a cassandra cluster following below link from datastax in which we have set inital_tokens into new cluster.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsSnapshotRestoreNewCluster.html

Migration is successful, My question is that we have set inital_tokes on new cluster similar to old cluster, Now i want to decommission some of the nodes of new cluster. 
1. What are the considerations or changes required before using nodetool decommission command 
2. What will happen to the data if i remove the node by decommissioning because initial_tokens is still set in all the cassandra nodes

Please help me on above questions

Comment: Is there replication factor set > 1 for all key spaces? If yes we may decommission the nodes and recalculate the token ranges for the existing ones such that decommissioned nodes ranges can be reassigned to some other nodes. then run a nodetool repair on all nodes.

Comment: yes the replication factor is set to 3 for all the keyspaces. We are also using Vnode, does recalculating the token ranges also apply to vnode configuration

Comment: with vnodes we dont need to

Comment: Thanks Praneeth, so this means i can directly decommission the nodes and cassandra will balance the data, without having to change anything.

Comment: But if initial_tokens is set it will override the num_tokens setting. We cant use Vnodes and Intial tokens at the same time

Comment: Using both the options together was recommended by datastax in below link while migration of data from one cluster to another https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsSnapshotRestoreNewCluster.html.

Comment: Also please note in cassandra documentation of initial_tokens, it is mentioned that we can use both the setting together http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html Please read num_tokens and initial_token

Answer (score 0):

Update:
As per the documentation http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html, We can use initial_tokens along with num_tokens. However initially when cluster is set up initial_tokens setting will take precedence over num_tokens and from subsequent restarts num_tokens will take prcedence over initial_tokens setting.

So in my use, I have performed rolling restart on cassandra cluster and then started decommissioning nodes one by one.